# WIQL tree query to get all parent work items from single child Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, wiql, azure-devops-rest-api

I have this WIQL...

```
Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
  {
    Query = string.Format("SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State]" +
                          " FROM WorkItemLinks" +
                          " WHERE Target.[System.TeamProject] = '{0}'" +
                          " AND Source.[System.Id] = {1}" +
                          " AND [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'" +
                          " mode(Recursive)", project, startingChildId)
  };
```

And I want to make it match this TFS Query where all parents of a particular work item are put into a tree as seen below.

[image]

My problem is that I'm only getting the child work items from the case that I want the parent work items. How can I traverse up the tree rather than down it? I have already tried switching `System.Links.LinkType` to the parent relation equivalent, but doing so throws an unsupported error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the WIQL below:

```
select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State]
 from WorkItemLinks
 where ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward')
  and (Target.[System.Id] = 4839)
 order by [System.Id]
 mode (Recursive, ReturnMatchingChildren)
```